# How to Show selected value on textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I show the value of the selected items in the textbox using javascript?

```
// MY LIST
<select id="list" class="form-control" multiple="">
  <option value="2014">Your Cute</option>
  <option value="2013">Your Ugly</option>
  <option value="2011">Your Awesome</option>
</select>

// BUTTON and TEXTBOX
<button onclick="show_value();" type="button" value="Get Value">Get Value</button>

<input type="text" id="selectedvalue" class="text" name="selectedvalue" />
```

I came up with this javascript code

```
function showgroup_id () {
    $('#selectedvalue').val(selectedvalue);  
    var myList = document.getElementById('list');
    var selected-value = selectedItem;
    var selectedGroupIds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].selected) {
            selectedselectedItem.push(myList[i].value);             
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried, it doesn't work.. anyone can help me please?

Comment: "it doesn't work" -> Error message?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "it doesn't work" is the single most unhelpful thing you could tell us.  **What** doesn't work, **what** doesn't it do, **what** does it do that it shouldn't

Comment: just in case - you are trying to call 'show_value()' method and there is no definition for that instead its showing 'showgroup_id()' Method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/66cq4w9e/ is it what you want?

Comment: @AshadShanto yeah thats it.. but I want to show the value.. example the Your cute has "2014" value.. so when I click get value it must show 2014 on textbox is that possible?

Comment: Got it @AshadShanto I change the (result = result + " " + myList[i].txt;) into (result = result + " " + myList[i].value;) thank you so much..

Comment: @AshadShanto sir theres a little proble I copied all your code.. no edit but its not working? why? http://jsfiddle.net/hsf6yhxp/

Comment: @EFehm on the sidebar you'll find a codeWrap selectable list. Change that list to no wrap-in <head>. This says, don't wrap my js code, put it in <head>. Another thing is as you are using jQuery you must have a reference to it. So change the first selectable list(list of all supported frameworks) to a recent version of jQuery.

Comment: @AshadShanto got it.. but what should I add on the code to make it work on my html file?

Comment: First reference to the jQuery library using  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> in you <head> tag. Then add you js code in another <script> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onchange event to change the textbox content with changing select element.

HTML :

```
<select id="selectBox">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="messageTextBox" />
```

javaScript :

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
selectBox.onchange = function(){
    var textbox = document.getElementById("messageTextBox");
    textbox.value = this.value;
};
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bgj2fadu/)

**Your Solution :**

**HTMl :**

```
<select id="list" class="form-control" multiple="">
    <option value="2014">Your Cute</option>
    <option value="2013">Your Ugly</option>
    <option value="2011">Your Awesome</option>
</select>

// BUTTON and TEXTBOX
<button onclick="showgroup_id();" type="button" value="Get Value">Get Value</button>

<input type="text" id="selectedvalue" class="text" name="selectedvalue"  style="width: 55%;" />
```

**javaScript/jQuery :**

```
function showgroup_id () {
    var result = "";
    var selectedItem = $('#selectedvalue').val(selectedvalue);  
    var myList = document.getElementById('list');
    var selectedValues = selectedItem;
    var selectedGroupIds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].selected) {
            //selectedselectedItem.push(myList[i].value);
            //alert(myList[i].text);
            result = result + " " + myList[i].text;
            $("#selectedvalue").val(result);
        }
    }
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/66cq4w9e/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

give some `id` to button and remove `onclick`

```
<button id="getValue" type="button" value="Get Value">Get Value</button>
```

bind onclick event to button as shown below

```
$('#getValue').click(function(){
   var text = $('#list option:selected').text();
   $('#selectedvalue').val(text);
});
```

Comment: what if the button id changes for some reason? onclick seems a better option. isn't it?

Comment: chances of changing button `id` is less as far as button is not getting generated dynamically. And if in case `id` changes then developer can simply update it in binded click handler. `id` of select and input item can also be change, in that case we need to update a code regardless of function or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        function show_value()
        {
            $("#selectedvalue").val($("#list").val());
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="list" class="form-control" multiple="">
    <option value="2014">Your Cute</option>
    <option value="2013">Your Ugly</option>
    <option value="2011">Your Awesome</option>
</select>

// BUTTON and TEXTBOX
<button onclick="show_value();" type="button" value="Get Value">Get Value</button>

<input type="text" id="selectedvalue" class="text" name="selectedvalue"  style="width: 55%;" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `show_value()` function will be called when the button is clicked. Inside the function, I have set the value of the textbox with the value of the select list.

```
function show_value()
{
  $("#selectedvalue").val($("#list").val());
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for the OP.

Comment: The show_value() function will be called when the button is clicked. Inside the function, I have set the value of the textbox with the value of the select list. I used jquery for doing this, if you don't know the basic syntax of jquery, please google it. There are lots of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

replace your javascript code with the following:

```
function show_value() {
    document.getElementById("selectedvalue").value = document.getElementById( "list" )[ (document.getElementById( "list" )).selectedIndex ].text;
}
```